# Good way to shuffle lines in a textfile with DataFlow

Tags: shuffle, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a very long text file (few hundred GB) I'd like to shuffle the lines of. I'm wondering if there is a good way to do this with DataFlow. I imagine I would get a small shuffle if I just put the file in and had a ParDo that runs a DoFn that just outputs lines. But it would be better to get a more comprehensive shuffling of the file. Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good shuffle you can try associating each line a key which is the line's MD5/CRC/UUID and then group by this key. In the group by function (assuming no collisions), just output the lines.

Comment: Thank you--totally forgot about the power of hashing.